# Using .apply() on a Java method from rhino (JavaScript)

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I want to use rhino's (JavaScript's) `function.apply()` to pass arguments to a varags Java method, something like this:

```
function sprintf()
{
    return java.lang.String.format.apply(arguments);
}
sprintf("%d\n", 5);
```

But invoking `sprintf()` gives an error:

```
Error: can't find method java.lang.String.format().
```

I suppose this is because the `format()` method isn't a proper JavaScript function but a Java method, so it doesn't have `apply()` defined.  (Although that's not what the error message seems to say, so maybe not.)

I do find that I can add my own apply() method:

```
java.lang.String.format.apply = function() {}
```

But I can't see how to write `apply()` without `apply()`, if you see what I mean.  Any ideas?

Comment: Since Java "varargs" are actually implemented as an array, it may work to just pass the array directly to the Java function from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vincent Montressor

Here is a partial solution:

```
function sprintf(string) {
  var args = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 1);

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (!isNaN(args[i])) {
      args[i] = new java.lang.Integer(args[i]);
    }    
  }

  return java.lang.String.format(String(string), args);
}
```

There are several issues:

- In your implementation .format() method signature is not used properly i.e. first parameter should be string
- Numeric values in arguments list must be converted to proper java types.

Here is the sample call:

```
print(sprintf("Hello %s %d", "number", 2));
```

Which produces: "Hello number 2"

Comment: Thank you! I modified this slightly to create either `Double`s or `Long`s (depending on whether `Math.round()` modified the value), and the result meets my needs. Thanks much!

Comment: @Vincent If this answer solves your issue you should "accept" it. (Click the checkmark on the left of the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Is java.lang not found you use "format" {method} in **String** Object. If String.format found then use:

```
 format("Hello, %s!", [firstName]);
```

you formatString function create sprintf

```
function sprintf() {
    return String.format.apply(arguments);
}
```

In my opinion use **format()** function...